# Dedup using HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql, deduplication

I have a hive table with field 'a'(int), 'b'(string), 'c'(bigint), 'd'(bigint) and 'e'(string).
I have data like:

```
a  b  c   d   e
---------------
1  a  10  18  i
2  b  11  19  j
3  c  12  20  k
4  d  13  21  l
1  e  14  22  m
4  f  15  23  n
2  g  16  24  o
3  h  17  25  p
```

Table is sorted on key 'b'.
Now we want output like below:

```
a  b  c   d   e
---------------
1  e  14  22  m
4  f  15  23  n
2  g  16  24  o
3  h  17  25  p
```

which will be deduped on key 'a' but will keep last(latest) 'b'.

Is it possible using Hive query(HiveQL)?

Comment: This can be expressed in a very simple Map/Reduce job that has only a mapper.

Comment: But I need to do that using HIVE

Answer (score 1):

If column b is unique, Try follow hql:

```
select 
* 
from
(
    select max(b) as max_b
    from
    table
    group by a
) table1
join table on table1.max_b = table.b
```